# How to create an array or ndarray from a tuple of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, range, tuples, multidimensional-array

Say if I have

```
s=np.zeros((5,5))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])  #which is an ndarray

s2=[s[ix,1] for ix in range(2,5)],[s[ix2,1] for ix2 in range(2,5)]
([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]) #which is a tuple
```

How can I make s2 into an array or ndarray?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is "array"? What shape should the result have? have you tried `numpy.concatenate()`?

Comment: Does `numpy.array(s2)` not give you what you want?

Comment: Why is it a tuple?  You used a list comprehension to build it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the obvious, use `np.array()`

```
s2 = np.array(s2)
```